# Command line lucene app

Tags: command-line, lucene

[Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/wiki/ChangeLog) is a great app for working with lucene indexes.  Does it have a command line interface?  Are there alternatives?  Do the alternatives offer a command line interface?

Comment: What kind of actions do you want to execute against your index?

Comment: Sure.  I'd love to have an answer.

Comment: Maybe the Solr Luke Handler is something for you. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler

Comment: Check "clue" command line tool: https://github.com/javasoze/clue/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[lucli](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/lucli.1.html) looks like a command-line alternative. It comes with the Lucene package. Look under the contrib folder.